# Permission Denied Error when downloading a file

Tags: r

I am trying to download an excel zip file into a R Project folder that I have started. I'm new to R so I'm a little puzzled at the error message that I'm receiving.

The file is an excel file and so first I created a variable for the file:

```
excel2file="http://op.nsf.data/dataFiles/Housing2013EXCEL.zip"
```

Then I used the coding:

```
download.file(excel2file, destfile= "~/Home/Documents/Data")
```

I receive this error message:

```
Error in download.file(excel2file, destfile = "~/Home/Documents/Data") : 
  cannot open destfile '~/Home/Documents/Data', reason 'Permission denied'
```

I tried looking at other examples of permission denied and I think it may be my destination file but I am not sure why or the steps to trouble shoot it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`destfile` should be a filename, not a directory. For example:

```
download.file(excel2file, destfile= "~/Home/Documents/Data/Housing2013EXCEL.zip")
```

Also, that URL doesn't seem to be valid, but that's a different (non-R) problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have the file already open in the `destfile`, as the `Permission denied` error also comes from being unable to overwrite an open file.

This tripped me up for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the package `readr` and its function `read_csv`. It allows you to download the file, but it has to be a downloaded files such as a CSV file, something like this worked for me

```
library(readr)

newz <- read_csv("https://www.stats.govt.nz/assets/Uploads/Annual-enterprise-survey/Annual-enterprise-survey-2020-financial-year-provisional/Download-data/annual-enterprise-survey-2020-financial-year-provisional-csv.csv")

View(newz)
```

about the "Permission Denied" I still doesn`t solved that problem

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `basename` with `paste`, which would be useful if downloading a bunch of files.

For example:

```
(excel2file="http://op.nsf.data/dataFiles/Housing2013EXCEL.zip")
(file_name <- basename(excel2file))

download.file(excel2file, destfile= paste("~/Home/Documents/Data",file_name, sep="/"))
```

Answer (score -3):

add a name in destfile like /downloadedfile.csv"

Comment: This is already what the accepted answer is explaining.